Randomizing the position of two gratings
I am trying to create two circle gratings (one horizontal and one vertical) that are displayed simultaneously. In each trial, the positions of the two gratings should change randomly.
This is my code so far, but I don't know how to add the "randomization."
import psychopy.visual
import psychopy.event

win = psychopy.visual.Window(
    size=[1200, 600],
    units="pix",
    fullscr=False
)

grating = psychopy.visual.GratingStim(
    win=win,
    units="pix",
    size=[400,400]
)

grating.sf = 5.0 / 150.0

grating.mask = "circle"

orientations = [0.0, 90.0]
grating_hpos = [-300, 300]

for i_grating in range(2):
    grating.ori = orientations[i_grating]
    grating.pos = [grating_hpos[i_grating], 0]
    grating.draw()

win.flip()

psychopy.event.waitKeys()

win.close()


For the randomisation you can use normal python or numpy functions, i.e. you don't need to take this from psychopy. Thus you can simply use np.random to randomly select versions of your trials.
Once you include the loop over trials you will have something like:
import numpy as np

for i_trial in range(n_trials):
    if np.random.rand() >= 0.5:
        position = 0
    else:
        position = 1
    # save the position to your data here!

    for i_grating in range(2):
        grating.ori = orientations[i_grating]
        # the next line works due to -1 indexing the last element
        # feel free to use more verbose clearer code that sets the positions based on the position variable 
        grating.pos = [grating_hpos[position-i_grating], 0]
        grating.draw()
    


